# Duplicate and giving identity to movieclips

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, adobe, clone

I have a question regarding array and snap function to ask about on ActionScript3

I am creating a simple cube game which requires players to drag cubes of different colors together and the cubes would snap on the right of each other.

Cubes are able to duplicate infinitely from a master stationary cube and they are all MovieClips.

I have conditioned cubes of different colors to snap into position as I've wanted but here is the problem...

Cubes for example red, will not snap together as each duplicated cube does not have its personal identity like red1, red2, red3 and so on as they do not know who to snap to due to the fact that both would be called reddup.

I've read up on duplicating cubes and numbering it at the same time using dynamic array, but I have no clue how to implement it into my game.

Comment: for each cube you can set `.name` so have a `var like redCount = 0` then later whenever you make a cube your function says `redCount += 1;` to add +1 to amount followed by `var myCube : RedCube = new RedCube();` then `myCube.name = "red" + redCount;` which means every new instance of Redcube has a unique name...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to not work with explicit names.

An instance name is just a reference to an object. But there are other ways to reference objects that do not require individual names. An array is an example for that. Just add the cube objects to the array:

```
var cubes:Array = [];

// then

cubes.push(new Cube());
```

You can then iterate over the array via an index:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < cubes.length; i++)
{
    cubes[i] // this is the i-th cube, use it like an instance name
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I would try it out later on but do I have to set an array 1 by 1 or is there a type of array that is expandable? Thank you again

Comment: @user6588766: as I said: you add objects to the array, which implies that it expands. Having an array per object doesn't make much sense, because you'd still have the same problem of identifying them.